# Using PyPi official repo with pygradle

Tags: python, gradle, pypi, pygradle

I'm trying to build and install my python library using new [PyGradle plugin](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle) from LinkedIn. I immediately run into problems because the [the demo repo](https://linkedin.jfrog.io/linkedin/pypi-external/pypi/) is very limited

```
repositories {
    pyGradlePyPi()
}
```

I would like to be able to pull dependencies from the official pypi.python.org repo but to my surprise there's no mention of it in the documentation I was able to dig out from the PyGradle's GitHub site. Is it possible at all and if not what can I do?

P.S. Based on the pygradle documentation there is no direct way of using PyPi repo since it utilizes Ivy to do the actual dependence management. It would be great to get an "official" tutorial on how to setup local and Artifactory-based repos and import needed packages

Comment: There's an active discussion about this at https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/issues/111

Comment: More on inability to use PyPi here: https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle#pypi-artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer - according to documentation direct import from PyPi is not supported. There's a pivy-importer utility that is capable of pulling packages from PiPy into the local Ivy repo but it is also pulling some default packages and needs to be extended (manually) to pull packages that you may need.
This is as I understand a work in progress and may be improved as project matures